# How to display a collection for admins

Tags: structure

I'm creating a structure page for collections. What is the best way to display collections by year? Should I use tags? How can I implement that?﻿

Answer (score 2):

[How do I create an “Archive” page for my entries?](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/entry-archive) covers this.